# How to write media queries for 1360*768 Screen?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I am  working on media queries for my site.

I created media queries for 1024 x 768 screen size, and it works well. I created a media query for 1360 x 768 screen size also, but it's not working. Here is what I've got so far:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) { 
  #loginrow { 
    padding: 135px 0; 
  } 
}

@media (max-width: 1360px) { 
  #loginrow { 
    padding: 135px 0; 
  } 
}
```

Can anyone suggest how this can be correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use min-widths, when you hit the higher resolution your queries will override what came before it.

```
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px){ #loginrow{ padding: 135px 0; } }
@media (min-width: 1360px){ #loginrow{ padding: 135px 0; } }
```

Comment: Hi paul thanks for your help. I added to my css screen page gives scrolling. When this same page checking with web developer tool it give correct out put what i want.